# ¿Cómo insertar múltiples imágenes en un mismo input en PDO?

Tags: pdo

Actualmente estoy tratando de hacer una inserción de varias imágenes en un mismo `input` pero no logro que funcione:

Configuración del `input`:

```
<input type="file" name="imagen[]" multiple="true" accept="image/*">
```

Método para insertar:

```
<?php

//error_reporting( ~E_NOTICE ); // avoid notice

include '../conexion/conexion.php';

if(isset($_POST['guardar'])){

foreach($_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name ){



$fk_categorias = $_POST['fk_categorias'];
$precio = $_POST['precio'];
$descripcion = $_POST['descripcion'];
$detalles = $_POST['detalles'];

$imgFile = $key.$_FILES['imagen']['name'][$key];
$tmp_dir = $_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'];
$imgSize = $_FILES['imagen']['size'];


if(empty($_POST["fk_categorias"])){
  $errMSG = "Por favor ingrese la categoria.";
}
else if(empty($precio)){
  $errMSG = "Por favor ingrese el precio.";
}
else if(empty($descripcion)){
  $errMSG = "Por favor ingrese la descripcion del articulo.";
}
else if(empty($detalles)){
  $errMSG = "Por favor ingrese algun detalle para el articulo.";
}

else if(empty($imgFile)){
  $errMSG = "Por favor Seleccione los Archivo de imagen.";
}
else
{
  $upload_dir = '../galerias/'; // upload directory

  $imgExt = strtolower(pathinfo($imgFile,PATHINFO_EXTENSION)); // get image extension

  // valid image extensions
  $valid_extensions = array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif'); // valid extensions

  // rename uploading image
  $imagen = rand(1000,1000000).".".$imgExt;

  // allow valid image file formats
  if(in_array($imgExt, $valid_extensions)){     
    // Check file size '5MB'
    if($imgSize < 5000000)        {
      move_uploaded_file($tmp_dir,$upload_dir.$imagen);
    }

    else{
         $errMSG = "¡ Ups Aviso: Lo siento, su archivo es demasiado grande !";
         //header("refresh:5;registrar_multiple.php");

    }
  }
     else{
          $errMSG = "¡ Ups Aviso: Lo sentimos, sólo se permiten archivos JPG, JPEG, PNG y GIF !";
          header("refresh:5;registrar_multiple.php");
    }
}


// si no hay errores continuo ....
if(!isset($errMSG))
{

  $sql=$DB_con->prepare("INSERT INTO detalles_categorias (fk_categorias, precio, descripcion, detalles) VALUES 
  (:fk_categorias, :precio, :descripcion ,:detalles)");
  $sql->bindParam(':fk_categorias',$_POST['fk_categorias']);
  $sql->bindParam(':precio',$_POST['precio']);
  $sql->bindParam(':descripcion',$_POST['descripcion']);
  $sql->bindParam(':detalles',$_POST['detalles']);
  $last_id = $DB_con->lastInsertId();

  $sql->execute();


  $sql2=$DB_con->prepare("INSERT INTO detalles_img (id, imagen) VALUES 
  (:id, :imagen)");
  $sql2->bindParam(':id',$_POST['last_id']);
  $sql2->bindParam(':imagen',$_POST['imagen'][$i]);
  $sql2->execute();


  if($sql2->execute())
  {

    $successMSG = "¡ Bien Hecho: Registro Insertado Correctamente !";
    header("refresh:5;registrar_multiple.php");

  }
  else
  {

          $errMSG = "¡ Ups Aviso: Hubo un error al insertar el registro !";
          header("refresh:5;registrar_multiple.php");


        }
      }
    }
 }
?>
```

Me da siguiente error de mensaje:

> **$errMSG = "¡ Ups Aviso: Lo siento, su archivo es demasiado grande !";**

Comment: El error te dice donde está el fallo en el código: ¿alguna de las imágenes excede el tamaño máximo permitido (5MB)? Aparte de eso, hay otro fallo: no se inicializa la variable `errMSG` en cada vuelta del bucle, eso hace que en cuanto una imagen incumpla las condiciones, las siguientes imágenes tendrán un `errMSG` y tampoco se guardarán (aunque cumplan todas las condiciones). Lo que me lleva a la pregunta: ¿se inserta alguna de las imágenes? Porque igual el problema es eso, y entonces se insertarían alguna imágenes pero no todas.

Comment: gracias alvaro por tu respuesta era un error en varias lineas de codigo: tenai que ser asi `$imgFile = $key.$_FILES['imagen']['name'][$key];
    $tmp_dir = $_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'][$key];
    $imgSize = $_FILES['imagen']['size'][$key];`  y en el sql2   `$sql2->bindParam(':imagen',$imagen);` pero el problema que tengo ahora es que me repite los registros en la tabla detalles categorias me imagino que debe ser por el foreach pero lo sque del primer sql y me da el mjs **Por favor Seleccione los Archivo de imagen.**  y que no me esta guardando el last_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pude resolverlo anexo el código para quien le pueda servir gracias a un amigo por su gran ayuda

```
<!-- proceso para registrar-->
<?php
error_reporting( ~E_NOTICE ); // avoid notice
include '../conexion/conexion.php';
if (isset($_POST['guardar'])) {
$fk_categorias = $_POST['fk_categorias'];
$precio        = $_POST['precio'];
$descripcion   = $_POST['descripcion'];
$detalles      = $_POST['detalles'];



if (empty($fk_categorias)) {
    $errMSG = "Por favor ingrese la categoria.";
} else if (empty($precio)) {
    $errMSG = "Por favor ingrese el precio.";
} else if (empty($descripcion)) {
    $errMSG = "Por favor ingrese la descripcion del articulo.";
} else if (empty($detalles)) {
    $errMSG = "Por favor ingrese algun detalle para el articulo.";
}
if (empty($errMSG)) {
    $imagen_bd = array();
    foreach ($_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name) {
        if ( ! empty($errMSG)) {
            //echo $errMSG;
            header("refresh:5;registrar_multiple.php");
            break;
        }
        $imgFile          = $key . $_FILES['imagen']['name'][$key];
        $tmp_dir          = $_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'][$key];
        $imgSize          = $_FILES['imagen']['size'][$key];
        $upload_dir       = '../galerias/'; // upload directory
        $imgExt           = strtolower(pathinfo($imgFile, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)); // get image extension
        //validar la extension de la imagen
        $valid_extensions = array(
            'jpeg',
            'jpg',
            'png',
            'gif'
        ); // valid extensions
        // rename uploading image
        $imagen           = rand(1000, 1000000) . "." . $imgExt;
        $imagen_bd[]      = $imagen;
        // allow valid image file formats
        if (in_array($imgExt, $valid_extensions)) {
            // Check file size '5MB'
            if ($imgSize < 10000000) {
                move_uploaded_file($tmp_dir, $upload_dir . $imagen);
            } else {
                $errMSG = "¡ Ups Aviso: Lo siento, su archivo es demasiado grande !";
                header("refresh:5;registrar_multiple.php");
            }
        } else {
            $errMSG = "¡ Ups Aviso: Lo sentimos, sólo se permiten archivos JPG, JPEG, PNG y GIF !";
            header("refresh:5;registrar_multiple.php");
        }
    }
    // si no hay errores continuo...
    $sql = $DB_con->prepare("INSERT INTO detalles_categorias (fk_categorias, precio, descripcion, detalles) VALUES (:fk_categorias, :precio, :descripcion ,:detalles)");
    $sql->bindParam(':fk_categorias', $fk_categorias);
    $sql->bindParam(':precio', $precio);
    $sql->bindParam(':descripcion', $descripcion);
    $sql->bindParam(':detalles', $detalles);
    $sql->execute();
    $last_id = $DB_con->lastInsertId();
    foreach ($imagen_bd as $img) {
        $sql2    = $DB_con->prepare("INSERT INTO detalles_img (id, imagen) VALUES (:id, :imagen)");
        $sql2->bindParam(':id', $last_id);
        $sql2->bindParam(':imagen', $img);
        if ($sql2->execute()) {
            $successMSG = "¡ Bien Hecho: Registro Insertado Correctamente !";
            header("refresh:5;registrar_multiple.php");
        } else {
            $errMSG = "¡ Ups Aviso: Hubo un error al insertar el registro !";
            header("refresh:5;registrar_multiple.php");
        }
    }
} else {
    //echo $errMSG;
    //header("refresh:5;registrar_multiple.php");
  }
 }
 ?>
 <!-- fin proceso para registrar-->
```

Answer (score 1):

Te había puesto esto como comentario, pero te lo voy a poner como respuesta, porque excede el tamaño y puede que sea donde encuentras los problemas. El código que compartes presenta varios errores que pueden hacer que no funcione:

1. No se inicializa la variable `errMSG` en cada vuelta del bucle, eso hace que **en cuanto una imagen incumpla las condiciones, las siguientes tendrán un `errMSG` y no se guardarán** (aunque cumplan todas las condiciones).
2. **Estás llamando a `lastInsertedId` antes de que se ejecute la sentencia de inserción**, por lo que el valor de `$last_id` seguramente será algo que no te esperas (al menos no para el primer registro).
3. Relacionado con  lo de arriba: parece que estás usando una variable incorrecta para realizar la inserción en la tabla "detalles_img". Si te fijas, **estás guardando el último id insertado en la variable `$last_id`, pero luego usas `$_POST["last_id"]`** que puede no estar definida.

El error que muestras te dice donde está el fallo en el código: ¿alguna de las imágenes excede el tamaño máximo permitido (5MB)? En cuanto ocurra con una, el resto de imágenes fallará (por lo descrito en el punto 1).

Si, como se describe en el punto 3, el problema es que `$_POST["last_id"]` no está definido, entonces no se realizará ninguna inserción en la tabla "detalles_img" y sólo una en la tabla "detalles_categorias" (el primero), porque a partir de ese momento (y por el problema descrito en el punto 1), el resto de imágenes tendrá error.

Comment: en  mysql se usa $last_id = mysql_insert_id();, como deberia usarse en pdo

Comment: Lo que digo es que debes ponerlo después de que se realice la inserción. Si lo pones antes, ¿qué valor te va a devolver?

Comment: ya resolvi lo del $last_id, lo que me falta ahora es evitar que se me dupliquen los registros en la primera tabla se que esto es ocasionado por el foreach porque la tabla detalles_categorias esta dentro del foreach, pero lo saque y puse el foreach solamente en la tabla detalles_img pero me da el mjs de que debe seleccionar las imagenes

Answer (score 0):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y ESTO, USANDO CONEXION MYSQLI COMO HARIA PORFAVOR, YA QUE LO ANTERIOR CONDIGO ESTA EN PDO Y ALGUNOS CODIGOS TIENEN QUE CAMBIARSE..