# upload php multiple

Tags: php, formularios, upload

Tengo este codigo php para upload y funciona bien pero solo almacena de un archivo, como hago para que reciba multiples

```
<?php 


$nombre=$_FILES['archivo']['name'];
$guardado=$_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'];

if(!file_exists('archivos')){
    mkdir('archivos',0777,true);
    if(file_exists('archivos')){
        if(move_uploaded_file($guardado, 'archivos/'.$nombre)){
            echo "File saved successfully";
        }else{
            echo "File could not be saved";
        }
    }
}else{
    if(move_uploaded_file($guardado, 'archivos/'.$nombre)){
        echo "File saved successfully";
    }else{
        echo "File could not be saved";
    }
}

?>
```

Tengo este codigo php para upload y funciona bien pero solo almacena de un archivo, como hago para que reciba múltiples

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo insertar múltiples imágenes en un mismo input en PDO?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/59881/c%c3%b3mo-insertar-m%c3%baltiples-im%c3%a1genes-en-un-mismo-input-en-pdo)

Comment: Sugiero que pongas un `var_dump($_FILES);` y agregues el resultado a la pregunta pulsando en [edit]. Lo primero que hay que ver es si están llegando todos los archivos que esperas. Si son varios tendrías que sacarlos con un bucle, pero ni siquiera sabemos si están llegando todos.